# Calculating a unit normal to the level surface at the point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a problem with this question:

Calculate a unit normal $\hat n$ to the level surface $\phi=0$ ($\phi=x^2+y^2-z^2-1$) at the point **r**=**$\hat j$** and sketch the level surface $\phi=0$. Your diagram should include the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis. Include the vector $\hat n$ in your diagram. Hint: To construct the sketch, write $\phi$ in cylindrical polar coordinates $\rho $, $\psi $ , z and use $\phi=0$ to find z as a function of the radial coordinate $\rho $.

As a normal to the level surface is $\nabla \phi$, and the unit vector is the vector divided by its magnitude, I calculated $\hat n=(\nabla \phi)/(|\nabla \phi|)$, which is

$\hat n=\frac{2x \hat i +2y \hat j -2z \hat k }{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} =\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\hat i+ \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\hat j-\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\hat k$

At the point **r**=$\hat j$ which is $R=(0,1,0)$, $\hat n=\hat j$. Is this true?

Also, I am unsure how to proceed to the sketching part of the question.

Rewriting the field in cylindrical polar coordinates, would it be

$\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$\psi=arctan\frac{y}{x}$

$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$ ?

What next?

Comment: What was your original function $\phi$?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that I didn't write it. It's edited now.

Comment: If you notice that you can negate the $z$-component of any point on the surface $\phi=0$ and get another point on the same surface, the surface is its own mirror image in the $x,y$ plane; and likewise it is its own mirror image in the $y,z$ plane. With those symmetries, it should be clear that _if_ the surface has a normal vector at $(0,1,0)$ then that normal vector _must_ be either the one you calculated or its negation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original equation $x^2+y^2-z^2 = 1$ can be written in cylindrical coordinates as $\rho^2 - z^2 = 1$.

Since this contains only $\rho$ and not $\psi$, this tells you that you can take a "cross-section" in any vertical plane (such as $x=0$ or $y=0$), and the level surface will be obtained by rotating that cross-sectional curve around the $z$-axis. Since $x^2-z^2=1$ is a hyperbola, you can rotate this around the $z$-axis to see that the surface is a one-sheeted hyperboloid.

Comment: @Rahul, thanks. I didn't notice that. I edited my post.